# Table data overflow the box

Tags: html, css

Anyone help me please The table td overflow the box please fix it.

```
**https://jsfiddle.net/Baloch007/njvLxzrp/**
```

Comment: jsfiddle link here                                                                                  https://jsfiddle.net/Baloch007/njvLxzrp/

Comment: Questions should include a [mcve] **in the question itself**. Without that, this is of no use to future readers.

Answer (score 2):

This is because there is no space between the word and single word will always come in one line by default.

If you want to break work according to table cell width use `word-break:break-all;` css

```
.device-information td {
  float: left;
   border:solid 1px #cecece;
   height:35px;
  width: 100%;
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/njvLxzrp/1/

> But this might be create problem if you apply this css in full table so i suggest you to give class to that cell and then apply css like this

**HTML**

```
<table class="device-information">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Device Name</th>
            <td class="longWord">alfalahhajshfjdhfjahdjfhdjhfjdhfjdhfjdhfjhdfjasfdfasdfdsafdasf</td>
            <td>alfalah</td>
            <td>alfalah</td>
            <td>alfalah</td>
            <td>alfalah</td>
            <td>alfalah</td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.device-information td.longWord {
   word-break:break-all;
}
```

Comment: Answering questions that have not been asked properly encourages more of them. Since Stack Overflow is intended to be a repository of knowledge, not a live help site, these sorts of questions and their answers provide no long term value, and are subject to closure and eventual deletion. You'll avoid frustration by not answering them. See: [Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind not showing the entire line of text and only indicate that there is more, you could add these lines

```
white-space:no-wrap;
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

to `.device-information td` on line 28

https://jsfiddle.net/vhnrn72z/

Comment: Answering questions that have not been asked properly encourages more of them. Since Stack Overflow is intended to be a repository of knowledge, not a live help site, these sorts of questions and their answers provide no long term value, and are subject to closure and eventual deletion. You'll avoid frustration by not answering them. See: [Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.device-information td {
  float: left;
  border:solid 1px #cecece;
  min-height:35px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
    -ms-word-break: break-all;

}
```

min-height: 35px ensures every td remains at least 35px of minimum height.

overflow-wrap: break-word; and word-wrap: break-word; literally just alternative name for each other. Some browser support one not the other.

word-break: break-all is for requiring a particular behaviour with CJK (Chinese, Japanese, and Korean) text, whereas word-wrap: break-word is the more general
So, my recommendation is, use both 3 of them.